# Completeness of $(C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}),d)$

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of all infinitely differentiable complex-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Define the metric
\begin{align}
d(f,g) = \sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n-m}\frac{\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x|\leq n} |f^{(m)}(x)-g^{(m)}(x)|}{1+\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x|\leq n} |f^{(m)}(x)-g^{(m)}(x)|}.
\end{align}
Show that $(C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}),d)$ is complete.

My attempt: Let $(f_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}),d)$. Then we know that $(f_k^{(m)}(x))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ for each $m\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$ and each $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is complete $(f_k^{(m)}(x))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ convergence to some $g_{m}(x)\in\mathbb{C}$ for each $m\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$ and each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Next, I want to show that $(f_k^{(m)})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ convergence uniformly to $g_{m}$ for each $m\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$ but not sure how to do it. At least I want to show that $g_{m}$ is continuous.

Comment: Convergence under your metric already enforces $f_k^{(m)}$ to converge uniformly to $g_m$ on $[-n, n]$ for each $n$, which is enough to prove $g_m$ is continuous. (It is actually not true that $f_k^{(m)}$ has to converge uniformly to $g_m$ on the entirety of $\mathbb{R}$: for example, just let $f_k(x) = \frac{x}{k}$.)

Comment: @DavidGao Yes, got that part. Have a candidate $g\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ (using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the dominated convergence theorem). What remains is to show that $f_k$ convergence to $g$ in $d$.

Comment: My advice would be to show that $f_j\to f$ for some $f$, and then show that for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, $\{f_j^{(n)}\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to the derivative of the limit function of $\{f_j^{(n-1)}\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$. This gives you that that $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and that the derivatives of all orders of the functions in your sequence converge to its derivatives

Comment: @BasicUser I presume you already know that if a sequence of functions and their derivatives both converge uniformly, then the derivatives must converge to the derivative of the limit function? That is enough to tell you on each $[-n, n]$, $f_k^{(m)} \to g^{(m)}$ uniformly, which is equivalent to convergence under your metric.

Comment: @DavidGao I struggle with the last assertion.

Comment: @BasicUser You mean that if on each $[-n, n]$, $f_k^{(m)} \to g^{(m)}$ uniformly, then $d(f, g) \to 0$?

Comment: @DavidGao correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this seems to be where OP is struggling, I’m writing answer to prove the following: if on each $[-n, n]$, $f_k^{(m)} \to g^{(m)}$ uniformly, then $d(f_k, g) \to 0$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists $N > 0$ s.t. $\sum_{n \geq N \vee m \geq N} 2^{-n-m} < \epsilon/2$ (here, $\vee$ means or). Thus,

$$d(f_k, g) < \sum_{n, m = 0}^{N-1} 2^{-n-m}\frac{\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x|\leq n} |f^{(m)}(x)-g^{(m)}(x)|}{1+\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x|\leq n} |f^{(m)}(x)-g^{(m)}(x)|} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Since for each $n$ and $m$, on $[-n, n]$, $f_k^{(m)} \to g^{(m)}$ uniformly, there exists $K > 0$ s.t., whenever $k \geq K$,

$$\frac{\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x|\leq n} |f^{(m)}(x)-g^{(m)}(x)|}{1+\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x|\leq n} |f^{(m)}(x)-g^{(m)}(x)|} < \frac{2^{n + m}}{2N^2}\epsilon$$

For all $n, m \leq N$. Thus, whenever $k \geq K$,

$$\begin{split}
d(f_k, g) &< \sum_{n, m = 0}^{N-1} 2^{-n-m}\frac{\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x|\leq n} |f^{(m)}(x)-g^{(m)}(x)|}{1+\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x|\leq n} |f^{(m)}(x)-g^{(m)}(x)|} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&< \sum_{n, m = 0}^{N-1} 2^{-n-m} \frac{2^{n + m}}{2N^2}\epsilon + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&= \epsilon
\end{split}$$

So $d(f_k,g) \to 0$, as required.